# How to show the Most Viewed Taxonomy in 24 hrs (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show the top / most viewed taxonomy in last 24 hrs.

URLS are like 
In admin: http://domain.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=store&post_type=coupon_type

On live site: http://domain.com/store/merchant-name

Currently using this code to show taxonomy

```
  <?php // taxonomies
  $id = get_the_ID();
  foreach ( get_object_taxonomies( get_post_type($id) ) as $taxonomy ) {
    $terms_list = get_the_term_list( $id, $taxonomy, '', '<span class="tax-sep">'.__( ',    ', 'twentytwelve' ).'</span>','' );
    if ( $terms_list ) 
     {
          echo $terms_list;
     }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Taxonomies aren't tracked for number of views. You could buy a plugin such as [this plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/popularity-filtering-and-view-tracking-wp-plugin/7791634) - I've never used it. Or you could build your own hook for tracking individual taxonomies in transients.

One thing to keep in mind is caching, make sure you're not using a very hard cache so that you're not catching all your tracking data.

Answer (score 0):

**Most viewed post of custom post type**

[Using this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/baw-post-views-count/)

```
Install it in your theme and use taxonomy code format and 

get most view taxonomy post  using
```

> 'meta_key' => 'views'

[And custom post type code hear](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89880/most-viewed-post-of-custom-post-type):